# Groovy sort String format docker tags in numerical order

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have an array of docker image tags values in string format. I was to sort the values in numerical and display in descending order.

How can I change the below code to sort in numerical order?

```
class Sorting {
    def static main(args) {   
        def d=["1.0.25.3306",
               "0.7.25.3307",
               "40.56.25.3308",
               "8.78.25.3309",
               "4.12.25.3310",
               "6.23.25.3311",
               "23.45.25.3312",
               "12.89.25.3313",
               "7.0.25.3314",
               "20.5.25.3315",
               "8.67.25.3316",
                ]

        println d.sort()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort` (or `toSorted`) methods with a custom comparator. Keep in mind, that `sort(Closure comparator)` mutates the input list, so you may want to use either:

- `sort(boolean mutate, Closure closure)`
- or `toSorted(Closure closure)`

method that creates a new list and keeps the input list unmodified.

For the comparator, you get every version string, tokenize it by `.` character, and transform every token to the integer value. Without this part, you will keep comparing strings. Let me show you it by example:

```groovy
def d = ["1.0.25.3306",
       "0.7.25.3307",
       "40.56.25.3308",
       "8.78.25.3309",
       "4.12.25.3310",
       "6.23.25.3311",
       "23.45.25.3312",
       "12.89.25.3313",
       "7.0.25.3314",
       "20.5.25.3315",
       "8.67.25.3316",
]


def result = d.toSorted { a, b ->
    def (a1, a2, a3, a4) = a.tokenize(".")*.toInteger()
    def (b1, b2, b3, b4) = b.tokenize(".")*.toInteger()

    return a1 <=> b1 ?: a2 <=> b2 ?: a3 <=> b3 ?: a4 <=> b4
}

result.each { println it }
```

In the comparator closure, we take every version string and we tokenize it by the `.` character. Here we capture the output of `tokenize()` method into multiple variables using multiple assignment, so each part gets assigned to its own variable. Then we use spread operator `*.` to call `toInteger()` on each token, which by default is still a type of `String`. Once we represented two version strings to that form, we can use compare operator `<=>` to compare every part of the version. We use Elvis operator `?:` to compare the following part if the `a` and `b` in the current part has the same numeric value. If you run this example, you will get something like this in the output console.

```
0.7.25.3307
1.0.25.3306
4.12.25.3310
6.23.25.3311
7.0.25.3314
8.67.25.3316
8.78.25.3309
12.89.25.3313
20.5.25.3315
23.45.25.3312
40.56.25.3308
```

Comment: Jenkins gave `spread not yet supported for CPS transformation` message change the line to like this `def (a1, a2, a3, a4) = a.tokenize("\\.")`. now `result.reverse()` call giving this error `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.reverse() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: reverse(int), every(), every(groovy.lang.Closure), previous()`

Comment: @sfgroups, you can encapsulate sorting part in the function annotated with `@NonCPS` annotation, so it is not evaluated in the groovy-cps shell.